# Uploading different iphone/ipad application versions

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

I've developed an app and released it for free on the App Store. Let's say its name is xxx
I've now developed two new versions of the app:

- The first is for iPhone (paid)
- The second is for iPad (paid)

But now how can I upload these two new versions to have the same name of the free one?

Actually I need to release three apps for xxx, one for free, the second one for the iPhone (paid) and the last for iPad (paid).

If this is not valid please tell me what I must do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general convention is to name them like this:

- iPhone (paid):
- iPad (paid):  HD
- iPhone (free):  Lite

Comment: thanks, so now what i must to do?

do i upload the tow new application ussing **add version** in iTunesConnect OR i must upload separately as a new apps and write like this xxx HD and xxx   ??

Comment: They are actually seperate apps and Apple will need to approve them individually as they have a different set of requirements for iPad/iPhone, I think you'd only use add version if you wanted to publish an update to one of them.